# MacBook Pro Hard Drive DOA

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

Please don't suggest Option +R or Option + Command +R. I've tried it all and think I made my failing hard drive worse. I've taken my laptop to TWO different repairs shops and neither one of them have been able to get the data off of the hard drive. My option now is to wipe the drive clean and lose all my data, pictures, files, etc. I was told I could send the hard drive somewhere and pay a fee to have the data pulled off. Does anyone know who does this? It's a 2016 or 2017 so not that old. Any suggestions are much appreciated as this came out of nowhere and I don't have my laptop backed up on the cloud.

Comment: Go to [Rossman Group](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/) in NYC.  I’m not affiliated, just a happy customer.  If he can’t salvage your data, nobody else will.  The prices are actually quite reasonable.  But a cheaper insurance policy would be a Time Machine backup.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I assume it's too late to do a Time Machine backup?

Comment: If you cant access the drive, yeah.  That ship sailed.

Comment: You can search "mac data recovery" on your favorite search engine. There are a lot of companies that do this. And it **can** be expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did email  Rossman and they were very helpful and honest.  They don't think they can get the data off of it either. Apparently there was a recall on the SSD card that’s on my unit and I never was notified so didn’t get the new one. I’m going to call a company in Ca called DriveSaver and see if they can help.